# Encode all columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to encode all columns of a found row in a table.

I've tried:

Get the columns (Let's call this **query0**):

```
-- This returns `column_0`,`column_1`...

SELECT CONCAT('`', GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT  COLUMN_NAME
    SEPARATOR '`,`'
), '`') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name')
```

Concat the columns from **query0** above (Let's call this **query1**):

```
SELECT CONCAT(query0)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_0 = condition
```

Encode:

```
SELECT ENCODE((query1), 'my_key');
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you'd use that `CONCAT` at all in your query1, it's already a concatenated string and you're only passing a single argument. Unless this was just your way of breaking up a large query and `CONCAT` was duplicated. Also, `ENCODE` is deprecated. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to concat all the columns of a row, for instance: user_id=1, name='Linus' email='linus@a.com', I want to encode the string '1,Linus,linus@a.com'.

Answer (score 0):

With mysql 8 works

```
SELECT
AES_ENCRYPT(names, UNHEX(SHA2('My secret passphrase',512)))
FROM
(SELECT 
     names
FROM
    (SELECT      CONCAT('`', GROUP_CONCAT(
        COLUMN_NAME
        SEPARATOR '`,`'
    ), '`') names
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testdb' AND TABLE_NAME = 'r') t1
Where names LIKE '%authorid%') t2
;
```

With mysql 5.x

```
SELECT
  ENCRYPT(names, 'My secret passphrase')
FROM
(SELECT 
     names
FROM
    (SELECT      CONCAT('`', GROUP_CONCAT(
        COLUMN_NAME
        SEPARATOR '`,`'
    ), '`') names
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'hotel') t1
Where names LIKE '%title%') t2
;
```

The database name and Tablename you have to change and Where names LIKE '%Colum_name%' the Coulmn_name too